# Splitting a column in a csv file in Bash

Tags: bash, csv, unix

I would like to extract values from the second column in my csv file and store the extracted values in a new column.

sample of my dataset:

```
page_name      post_id                        page_id
A              86680728811_272953252761568    86680728811   
A              86680728811_273859942672742    86680728811
B              86680728033_281125741936891    86680728033
B              86680728033_10150500662053812  86680728033
```

I would like to extract the number that come after the underscore and store them in a new column. Sample output:

```
page_name      post_id                        page_id
A              272953252761568                86680728811   
A              273859942672742                86680728811
B              281125741936891                86680728033
B              10150500662053812              86680728033
```

I tried using this code:

```
cat FB_Dataset.csv | sed -Ee 's/(.*)post_id/\1post_id/' -e 's/,[_ ]/,/' -e 's/_/,/'
```

but I don't get the desired output.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/[0-9][0-9]*_//' < a.csv
```

where a.csv is the file with your original data
edited to add [0-9]

Comment: `[0-9]*_` removes `_` from `page_name`.  I suggest to replace `*` with `\+`.

Comment: when I use `'s/[0-9]*_//'` I get a new column called 'name' (splited from page_name) that contains the first part of the string (the number before the underscore) I wish to remove this column. And another column called 'post_id' which contains the required output.

Comment: when I use `'s/[0-9]\+_//'` I get an error "RE error: parentheses not balanced" and `'s/[0-9]\+_//'`returns an empty file. Thanks

Comment: There are no parenthesis, rather brackets. Also see my reply to @Cyrus - I will update my answer

Comment: @leena: Check your file for special characters: `cat -A FB_Dataset.csv`

Comment: if I use this ` 's/([0-9][0-9]+_)` or this ` 's/([0-9][0-9]\+_)` I still get the name column.

Comment: The original file contains around 500,000 rows. The function only returns 2000. I checked the special characters  I get `cat: illegal option -- A
usage: cat [-benstuv] [file ...]` I am really confused.

Comment: the entire file was printed when I used `LC_ALL=c sed` I still can't get rid of 'name' column though