# Using \1 to keep part of the pattern Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a csv file with 21 columns. I am working on the second column. I want to drop/delete the first part of the number, the part before the underscore. And keep the rest of the value.

sample dataset (first three columns)

```
page_name      post_id                        page_id
A              86680728811_272953252761568    86680728811   
A              86680728811_273859942672742    86680728811
B              86680728033_281125741936891    86680728033
B              86680728033_10150500662053812  86680728033
```

desired output

```
page_name      post_id                        page_id
A              272953252761568                86680728811   
A              273859942672742                86680728811
B              281125741936891                86680728033
B              10150500662053812              86680728033
```

I tried using \1 method and regex to remove the part I don't want and keep the rest of the string.

```
 cat FB_Data.csv | LC_ALL=c sed -Ee 's/.*\D(post_id)/\1post_id/' -e 's/_/,/'
```

but for unknown reason this method splits the header of the first column and adds a new column called 'name' with the values of page_id.

I also tried sub with awk but it is not working

```
awk -v "OFS=," '{$2=$2;sub(/[0-9]*_/, $2, $2);  print}' FB_Data.csv>output.csv
```

Any tip would be helpful. I have been stuck for two days trying to solve this. Thank you,

Comment: I suggest to continue at your last question: [Splitting a column in a csv file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58036419/3776858)

Comment: Thank you for referencing the question. I hope someone is able to help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk, `sub` modifies the target (the third parameter) directly, like this:

```
awk '
{ 
    sub("[0-9]+_","",$2);
    print
}' FBdata.csv
```

Comment: I tried the code. It returns the same input file, nothing changes. Thank you suspectus.